# Relation between universal enveloping von Neumann algebra and $C^*$-tensor products

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be unital $C^*$-algebras and let $\tilde A$ and $\tilde B$ be their universal enveloping von Neumann algebras. Let $C=A\otimes_\beta B$ be a $C^*$-tensor product of $A$ and $B$.

For which $\beta$ is there a relation between the universal enveloping von Neumann algebra $\tilde C$ and the von Neumann tensor product $\tilde A\overline\otimes \tilde B$ of the universal enveloping von Neumann algebras?